# Laravel seed database with special character in string

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

In Laravel, I am trying to seed my database with some textfields which could have special characters in them. When I execute `db:seed` it says it successfully seeded the database, but when I look in my database I'm seeing that it inserted everything except for the text after the special character (in that field).

This is how my seed looks like:

```
City::create(array(
  'name' => 'Groningen',
  'description' => 'A simple description with a special character é in it, and
   some content that for some reason won\'t be inserted to my database'
));
```

So to be clear: the text before the 'é' is inserted in the database, but the text beyond it is not. So my database will look like:

```
id   |  name           |  description
-----|-----------------|-------------------
1    |  Groningen      |  A simple description with a special character
```

My City model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model {


  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'cities';

}
```

My City migration file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCitiesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cities', function($t) {
            $t->increments('id');

            $t->string('name');
            $t->text('description');

            $t->double('latitude')->nullable();
            $t->double('longitude')->nullable();

            $t->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cities');
    }

}
```

And my config/database.php:

```
return [

    'default' => 'mysql',
    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'citydb',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'root',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],
    ],
    // The other Laravel default database.php config
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your description field has character limit. You should make sure it's long enough.

But if it's not the case, you should make sure you have your file encoded with correct encoding, you have your database created with correct encoding and the same you set in `app/config/database.php` (or `app/config/local/database.php`).

For example you could have set in this file:

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

and make sure your database (and table columns are set to `utf8_unicode_ci` and your file where you put your string is encoded as `UTF-8`.

Last option is your `City` Eloquent model. You should make sure you don't use here any mutators (for example `str_replace`, `substr` or similar functions that could trim the data or modify it in wrong way - for example using `substr` instead of `mb_substr`)

Comment: - The field limit isn't the problem (when I remove the special characters it works)

- I've set my database configuration like so

- I'm not doing anything but returning the data in my model, (which only returns the incorrect data from the database)

Comment: @DanielGelling Do you have any functions in your `City` model? Does it inherit from `Eloquent` or from 3rd party add-ons?

Comment: @MarnickNabialek No I don't. It only includes a protected $table;

Comment: @DanielGelling So probably you could attach your files: `City` model , migration (if you have any) or your database table, your database config file and the file you use for seeding

Comment: @DanielGelling I've reproduced the error when I save file with seeding NOT in `UTF-8` but for example in `ISO-8859-1`. Make sure you have this file in UTF-8 encoding and not in any other encodings what I already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Because I created a script which generated my seed file by placing PHP in a new file with `file_put_contents()` it didn't automatically set the file's encoding to UTF-8.